# ASP.NET Chart: How to specify color for pie chart?

Tags: asp.net, colors, charts, pie-chart

I have a pie chart and want to specify an exact color for a particular segment of the pie chart.

Which attribute do I use to specify the color dynamically? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color property hangs off the series object.

```
Chart.Series["xxx"].Color = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Interesting `"'` string syntax ;)

Comment: @Andomar: LOL...you've never seen that before? Its a cool new feature in .NET ;-)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I actually need specific color for a segment so I probably need to use: // Set color of a single data point Chart.Series[0].Points[5].Color = Color.Red; However, I get a compiler error at Color! ("does not exist in current context"). How do I fix this? Thanks.